# Dynamic groups based on ip range in Ansible groups

Tags: ansible

How to create variable group based on ip address-range in ansible inventory groups ? I have two groups of servers in different location. I want to create the groups every time the playbook so that the playbook is run on a updated list of servers. I already groups based on distribution, prod, dev, test, qa ,dr in my host inventory.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scan all hosts at the beginning and group them how you want, e.g. by network:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - group_by: key=network_{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}
```

This will create as many groups with names `network_<network>` as many different networks you have. But keep in mind that it need to gather facts from all hosts, so depending on count of hosts and speed of connections it can require significant time. Facts caching will speed up things, but anyway...

If you manage your inventory file by hand, consider manually specifying regional groups as well.

Comment: Just a follow up question, I understand how group by can be used using os-distribution. In that can we know what the groups would be called once they are formed into groups. If I use the above groups classification. How do I know what groups were created.? Also I would like to register the two IP ranges we have to a groups name like 'SB' and  'AD'.

Comment: You can use `group_by: key=SB` with `when: ansible_default_ipv4.network == '192.168.0.0'` or any other criteria

Comment: Is there a way that I could gather the hostnames of all the servers that fall under these categories . So that I can define them in my inventory rather than creating the groups every single time.

Comment: yes, there is an example how to enumerate hosts in group in the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).