# ansible dynamic group based on IP range

Tags: ansible

How to create variable group based on ip address-range in ansible inventory groups ? I have two groups of servers in different location. I want to create the two groups based on their IP range (two ranges for two locations) . I already  have groups based on distribution, prod, dev, test, qa ,dr in my host inventory. I know I can create a thr grouping using group_by. But How do I call them ? and How to assign a custom variable name to them ? 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - group_by: key=network_{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}

But how do I call them ?  and How to assign a custom variable name to them ? Is there a way that I could create a group once and store all the hosts in a  static inventory file. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571141/dynamic-groups-based-on-ip-range-in-ansible-groups/38572664?noredirect=1#comment64789811_38572664).

You can use `when` statement with `group_by` as with any other task.
For example:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
   - group_by: key=London
     when: ansible_default_ipv4.network == '192.168.0.0'
   - group_by: key=Paris
     when: ansible_default_ipv4.network == '10.0.0.0'
```